# how to select specific rows and columns

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, cut

I need to select for example:

- Column 2 of row 7.
- Column 3 of row 8.
- Columns 1 and 3 of row 11.

of a specific file and place the result in another file.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
sed -n -e '7p' -e '8p' -e '11p' Old_File | awk '{printf("%s %s %s\n", $2, $3, $1);}' > New_File.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk alone can get it done:

```
awk 'NR==7{print $2} NR==8{print $3} NR==11{print $1, $3}' Old_file > New_file
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Awk is a beast, I am really trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: There is a typo in `NR=8`. Like that it would print the third field of every line. `NR==8` better.

Comment: Thank you Birei and Prince John Wesley.

Answer (score 2):

`Awk` is enought for that task:

```
awk '
    FNR == 7 { print $2; next; }
    FNR == 8 { print $3; next; }
    FNR == 11 { print $1, $3; exit; }
' input-file
```

Comment: Birei thank you for editing my question and answering it also.